# Two Tablew in One Screen

Tags: ipad, uitableview, rss, nsmutabledictionary

I want to have two tables and a webview in one iPad screen from the following:

- The first table will parse items from an RSS feed, and will have an option for a
  checkmark
- The second table will be comprised of all checked items
- The webview will be the content from **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** from the first table (so basically the first table gives the opportunity to display content from didSelectRow, AND check a box (or whatever) to create the secondary table.

I am told for the second table, I should have the checks write to a plist with **NSMutableDictionary**, and then the second table will just be a table of the plist...but really, ***what's the code for this***?...where do I put it?...etc etc etc. And if the user unchecks the items, the line in the plist will be cleared, right???

I PRESUME I can show all three classes in one screen with something like

```
[viewController.view addSubview:someOtherViewControler.view];
```

Is there any reason why I should not do this??

Thanks so much!
XOXO

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you shouldn't do this, and you will be happier with your proposed approach than you would be if you tried to do it all with one view controller.

Organizing with design patterns is done to simplify design and maintenance of your software. What you have described is clearly three independent data sources each with their own independent views. You can use the MVC design pattern independently on each one of them. This independence lends itself to having separate view controllers that are easy to design and maintain.

The fact that they are collected into one main view for your application is outweighed by the simplification in maintainability that you will obtain with separate view controllers.